# How to type some text in hidden field in Selenium WebDriver using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

I am using WebDriver with PHP for data parse. I have the following HTML code for input field which is hidden:

```
<input class="" data-id="6" type="hidden" name="login">
```

How to type something in hidden field in Selenium Grid 4 (+php-webdriver)? I have written this code:

```
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('input[data-id="6"]'))->sendKeys('my_login');
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working example via javascript

```
$driver->executeScript("document.querySelector('input[data-id=\"6\"]').value='my_login';");
```